# I am trying to restore an Oracle DB, but I am getting strange controlfile errors. What do I do next?

Tags: oracle, rman, solaris, oracle-8i

Oracle version = Oracle 8i (817_312) //Yes I know this is old.

Database id = LED

OS = Solaris 8

Oracle USERID = oraled

Oracle DBA group =  dba

rman backups to disk.

Sorry this is so long.  I am not a DBA, I am UNIX/Linux system administrator. We lost our DBA a while ago, 
and I was told to keep it running.  What am I missing or doing wrong?

I am trying to restore an oracle database from a good backup and I am getting errors that there is a 
problem with the controlfiles. The oracle DB is up, mounted and open when this script runs. This is how we 
are backing up the oracle DB from Oracle's cron.

```
rman target / nocatalog cmdfile=/oracle/admin/led/rman/LEDlvl0 log=$LOGFILE
```

and in /oracle/admin/led/rman/LEDlvl0.sh we have

```
run {
set command id to 'LED_rman_test';
allocate channel disk1 type disk format '/apps1/backup/%d.LVL0.%s.%t.%p.dbf';
allocate channel disk2 type disk format '/apps2/backup/%d.LVL0.%s.%t.%p.dbf';
allocate channel disk3 type disk format '/apps3/backup/%d.LVL0.%s.%t.%p.dbf';
allocate channel disk5 type disk format '/apps5/backup/%d.LVL0.%s.%t.%p.dbf';
allocate channel disk6 type disk format '/apps6/backup/%d.LVL0.%s.%t.%p.dbf';


backup incremental level=0 setsize=7000000 database ;
backup (current controlfile format '/apps4/backup/%d.%s.%t.%p.ctl');


release channel disk1;
release channel disk2;
release channel disk3;
release channel disk5;
release channel disk6;
```

This ran succesfully. I want to restore this backup. I have removed the data files and copied the control file
(/apps4/backup/LED.22010.973362972.1.ctl) file back to the the locations specified by the initLED.ora file.

As the Oracle user these are the commands I am running.

```
$ rman nocatalog

RMAN> connect target sys/********@LED

RMAN>  startup mount
```

and I get this error

```
RMAN-06196: Oracle instance started
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-06003: ORACLE error from target database: ORA-00205: error in identifying controlfile, check alert log for more info
RMAN-06097: text of failing SQL statement: alter database mount
RMAN-06099: error occurred in source file: krmk.pc, line: 4192
```

and the alertLED.log shows:

```
Tue Apr 24 16:57:04 2018
Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
LICENSE_MAX_SESSION = 0
LICENSE_SESSIONS_WARNING = 0
LICENSE_MAX_USERS = 0
Starting up ORACLE RDBMS Version: 8.1.7.0.0.
System parameters with non-default values:
  processes                = 150
  sessions                 = 170
  timed_statistics         = TRUE
  event                    = 10183 trace name context forever, level 1,   
10191 trace name context forever, level 1
  shared_pool_size         = 400000000
  enqueue_resources        = 8000
  control_files = /oracle/LED/sapdata1/cntrl/cntrlLED.dbf, /oracle/LED/sapdata2/cntrl/cntrlLED.dbf, /oracle/LED/sapdata3/cntrl/cntrlLED.dbf
  db_block_buffers         = 142000
  db_block_size            = 8192
  db_block_lru_latches     = 4
  compatible               = 8.1.0
  log_archive_start        = TRUE
  log_archive_dest         = /oracle/LED/saparch/R3Parch
  log_archive_min_succeed_dest= 1
  log_buffer               = 1048576 
  log_checkpoint_interval  = 300000
  log_checkpoint_timeout   = 0
  db_files                 = 254
  db_file_multiblock_read_count= 8
  log_checkpoints_to_alert = TRUE
  control_file_record_keep_time= 45
  dml_locks                = 2500
  row_locking              = always
  replication_dependency_tracking= FALSE
  transactions_per_rollback_segment= 20
  max_rollback_segments    = 400
  rollback_segments        = PRS_0, PRS_1, PRS_2, PRS_3, PRS_4, PRS_5, PRS_6, PRS_7, PRS_8, PRS_9
  transaction_auditing     = FALSE
  remote_os_authent        = TRUE
  remote_login_passwordfile= EXCLUSIVE
  db_domain                = world
  audit_trail              = TRUE
  sort_area_size           = 2097152
  sort_area_retained_size  = 0
  db_name                  = LED
  open_cursors             = 800
  optimizer_mode           = choose
  optimizer_index_cost_adj = 10
  cursor_space_for_time    = FALSE
  parallel_max_servers     = 20
  hash_join_enabled        = FALSE
  background_dump_dest     = /oracle/LED/saptrace/background
  user_dump_dest           = /oracle/LED/saptrace/usertrace
  core_dump_dest           = /oracle/LED/saptrace/background
PMON started with pid=2
DBW0 started with pid=3
LGWR started with pid=4
CKPT started with pid=5
SMON started with pid=6
RECO started with pid=7
Tue Apr 24 16:57:07 2018
ARCH: STARTING ARCH PROCESSES
ARC0 started with pid=8
Tue Apr 24 16:57:07 2018
ARCH: STARTING ARCH PROCESSES COMPLETE
Tue Apr 24 16:57:07 2018
ARC0: Archival started
Tue Apr 24 16:57:07 2018
alter database mount
Tue Apr 24 16:57:07 2018
ORA-00202: controlfile: '/oracle/LED/sapdata1/cntrl/cntrlLED.dbf'
Tue Apr 24 16:57:10 2018
ORA-205 signalled during: alter database mount...
```

and

oerr 205 give me this:

```
$ oerr ora 205
00205, 00000, "error in identifying controlfile, check alert log for more info"
// *Cause:  The system could not find a controlfile of the specified name and
//         size.
// *Action: Check that ALL controlfiles are online and that they are the same
//         files that the system created at cold start time.
```

So I check the controlfiles:

```
$ ls -l /oracle/LED/sapdata1/cntrl/cntrlLED.dbf /oracle/LED/sapdata2/cntrl/cntrlLED.dbf /oracle/LED/sapdata3/cntrl/cntrlLED.dbf
-rw-r-----   1 oraled   dba      29876736 Apr 23 23:19 /oracle/LED/sapdata1/cntrl/cntrlLED.dbf
-rw-r-----   1 oraled   dba      29876736 Apr 23 23:19 /oracle/LED/sapdata2/cntrl/cntrlLED.dbf
-rw-r-----   1 oraled   dba      29876736 Apr 23 23:19 /oracle/LED/sapdata3/cntrl/cntrlLED.dbf
```

So I try and restore the controlfile.

```
$ rman nocatalog

RMAN> connect target sys/********@LED

RMAN> startup nomount


RMAN-06196: Oracle instance started

Total System Global Area    1609240736 bytes

Fixed Size                       73888 bytes
Variable Size                444837888 bytes
Database Buffers            1163264000 bytes
Redo Buffers                   1064960 bytes

RMAN> run {
2> allocate channel ch1 type disk;
3> allocate channel ch2 type disk;
4> allocate channel ch3 type disk;
5> allocate channel ch5 type disk;
6> allocate channel ch6 type disk;
7>
8> restore controlfile to '/apps6/backup/jimt.ctl';
9> }

RMAN-03022: compiling command: allocate
RMAN-03023: executing command: allocate
RMAN-08030: allocated channel: ch1
RMAN-08500: channel ch1: sid=10 devtype=DISK

RMAN-03022: compiling command: allocate
RMAN-03023: executing command: allocate
RMAN-08030: allocated channel: ch2
RMAN-08500: channel ch2: sid=11 devtype=DISK

RMAN-03022: compiling command: allocate
RMAN-03023: executing command: allocate
RMAN-08030: allocated channel: ch3
RMAN-08500: channel ch3: sid=12 devtype=DISK

RMAN-03022: compiling command: allocate
RMAN-03023: executing command: allocate
RMAN-08030: allocated channel: ch5
RMAN-08500: channel ch5: sid=13 devtype=DISK

RMAN-03022: compiling command: allocate
RMAN-03023: executing command: allocate
RMAN-08030: allocated channel: ch6
RMAN-08500: channel ch6: sid=14 devtype=DISK

RMAN-03022: compiling command: restore

RMAN-03022: compiling command: IRESTORE
RMAN-03026: error recovery releasing channel resources
RMAN-08031: released channel: ch1
RMAN-08031: released channel: ch2
RMAN-08031: released channel: ch3
RMAN-08031: released channel: ch5
RMAN-08031: released channel: ch6
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03002: failure during compilation of command
RMAN-03013: command type: restore
RMAN-03002: failure during compilation of command
RMAN-03013: command type: IRESTORE
RMAN-06003: ORACLE error from target database: ORA-01507: database not mounted
ORA-06512: at "SYS.X$DBMS_RCVMAN", line 4461
ORA-06512: at line 1
RMAN-06097: text of failing SQL statement: begin dbms_rcvman . setDatabase ( upper ( :dbname:dbname_i ) , :rlscn , :rltime , :fhdbi:fhdbi_i ) ; end ;
RMAN-06099: error occurred in source file: krmk.pc, line: 9196
```

I am stuck. Any ideas of what I should try next?

Thanks
JiM T

Answer (score 1):

The controlfile **BACKUP** you copied  is not the same as a controlfile.

Can you try

restore controlfile from '/path/to/controlfile_backup.ctl';

or failing that, check this out
"Oracle8i Recovery Manager User's Guide and Reference"
"Restoring the Control File from a Backup Set Without Using RMAN"
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a76990/rmanreco.htm#441496

Comment: I tried the above restore command and it failed.:  Here is the Error message:  RMAN> restore controlfile from '/apps4/backup/LED.22010.973362972.1.ctl';

RMAN-00558: error encountered while parsing input commands
RMAN-01005: syntax error: found "restore": expecting one of: "allocate, alter, beginline, catalog, change, connect, create, crosscheck, configure, debug, delete, drop, exit, endinline, host, {, library, list, mount, open, print, register, release, replace, report, renormalize, reset, resync, rman, rpct"
RMAN-01007: at line 1 column 1 file: standard input

Comment: My version of oracle is so old it doesn't support the restore from syntax.

Comment: Check out the second part of my answer where I give you a link to the Oracle doc that shows how to do a controlfile restore in 8i using PL/SQL, you don't need RESTORE FROM for that. Another thing you could try, copy the controlfile **backup piece** to a file called fred.zip. Try and unzip fred.zip. The very early versions of RMAN used zip.

Comment: When do you backup your ARCHIVELOGS?